# Can I define a union type of two interface that has same property but different values?

Tags: typescript

I just want to declare an union type `ShapeProps`, which may be `ShapeLine` or `ShapePoint`. Both `ShapeLine` and `ShapePoint` have property **type** and **style** with different values. Could I do it or something like this?

```
interface ShapeBase {
  fill: string
  stroke: string
}

type LineType = 'broken' | 'curve'

type LineStyle = 'dash' | 'dot' | 'line'

interface ShapeLine extends ShapeBase {
  type: LineType
  style: LineStyle
}

type PointType = 'circle' | 'rect'

type PointStyle = 'hollow' | 'solid'

interface ShapePoint extends ShapeBase {
  type: PointType
  style: PointStyle
}

type ShapeProps = ShapeLine | ShapePoint
```

Comment: Your code looks like it would work. What is your question / problem?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Just know that, with this setup `type` of `ShapeProps` can be `'broken' | 'curve' | 'circle' | 'test'`. If this is ok for you, then you have no problem.

Also, a little improvement you can do is to define generics within `ShapeBase`.
Change `ShapeBase` to following

`interface ShapeBase<T, S> {
  fill: string;
  stroke: string;
  type: T;
  style: S;
}
interface ShapeLine extends ShapeBase<LineType, LineStyle> {
} 
interface ShapePoint extends ShapeBase<PointType, PointStyle> {
}`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner That should work perfect. What if I have a new interface who also extends from `ShapeBase`, but it does not have **type** or **style**. In that case, I can not use generics within `ShapeBase`.

Comment: `@vanppo I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you could do that. You should just know that `type` of `ShapeProps` can be `'broken' | 'curve' | 'circle' | 'test'`. Also, since they have common attributes, why don't you move those to `ShapeBase` as follows

```js
interface ShapeBase<T, S> { 
    fill: string; 
    stroke: string; 
    type: T; 
    style: S; 
}

type LineType = 'broken' | 'curve';

type LineStyle = 'dash' | 'dot' | 'line';

interface ShapeLine extends ShapeBase<LineType, LineStyle> { }

type PointType = 'circle' | 'rect';

type PointStyle = 'hollow' | 'solid';

interface ShapePoint extends ShapeBase<PointType, PointStyle> { }

type ShapeProps = ShapeLine | ShapePoint;
```

If there is another interface which does not have `type` nor `style`, there are two things you could do

1- Create another interface without `<T, U>` and make `ShapeBase` extend this new interface.

2- You can `Omit` some attributes from any interface

`type TypelessShape = Omit<ShapeBase<'', ''>, 'type' | 'style'>;`